# System requirements for using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

I consider to use ASP.NET for developing a real-time appication that will be shown on a browser (IE, FF, Chrome etc.).

I'm wondering what are the system requirements for the server side where the application will be deployed?

- Do I have to use IIS or I'm free to choose any web server I want? If IIS only - does it part of any Windows installation (so users do not have to pay extra charge for that?)
- Do I have to install .NET Framework?
- anything else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use IIS, you could use Apache, nginx, or xsp, but doing so means you have to use mono which is an open source version of the .NET framework, it's a couple of versions behind the real thing, you can find out more info here: http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

If you choose to use Windows/IIS, then IIS is a feature of Windows that can be installed free of charge. You will need to install the .NET framework in order to host an ASP.NET web application, like IIS, the .NET framework and ASP.NET are features of Windows Server 2008 and above that can be installed/uninstalled whenever you like, for free.